# problems with 88x2bu card on Debian

Tags: wifi

I have bought  [this card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FCNP2VL) on Amazon

I connect the card to usb3 port OK

I download and install the driver

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702
make
make install
modprobe 88x2bu
```

No error on dmesg, all seems fine.

Then I start to configure the network firs with network manager

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

report my networks

```
***************  hotspot-2  Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 WPA3
***************  hotspot-1  Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 WPA3
```

I try to connect to the first one (I have the password)

```
nmcli device wifi connect hotspot-1 password 'mypass'
```

and return this error

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.
```

same thing for hotspot-2.

So I try the classic way (wpa_supplicant + dhclient)

I configured wpa_supplicant.conf

```
network={
ssid="hotspot-1"
psk="Thepass"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

I start the wpa_supplicant daemon and said..

```
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan1: Trying to associate with ********* (SSID='hospot-2' freq=5180 MHz)
nl80211: kernel reports: Authentication algorithm number required
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0
wlan1: Associated with ****
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=********* reason=2
wlan1: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="hotspot-2" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="hotspot-2"
```

So I tried another configuration

```
ssid="network SSID"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK-SHA256
psk=xxx
ieee80211w=2
```

I tried and..nothing happen

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: kernel reports: Authentication algorithm number required
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround found: I have installed Slackware 15 and the card works perfect with nmcli